# Is it possible for partial data match with onPost() using axios-mock-adapter?

Tags: javascript, axios, axios-mock-adapter

Environment:

```
NodeJS 8.1.2
axios 0.16.2
axios-mock-adapter 1.9.0
```

A test POST API call utilising [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) as follow:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter')

// Bootstrapping

const PlaceholderApp = {
  createComment: function (author, email, message) {
    const options = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
      data: {
        name: author,
        email: email,
        body: message,
      }
    }
    return axios(options)
  }
}

// Mock Adapter

const mockHttpClient = new MockAdapter(axios, { delayResponse: 50 })
// mockHttpClient.onPost(/(\/comments)/i, { name: 'author A', email: 'authorA@test.com', body: 'test comment' }).reply(526) // WORKS!
mockHttpClient.onPost(/(\/comments)/i, { email: 'authorA@test.com' }).reply(527) //This won't work. Would like to have something like this to work tho...
mockHttpClient.onAny().passThrough()

// Test cases

describe('PlaceholderApp.createComment', () => {
  it("should fail due to mock...", (resolve) => {
    PlaceholderApp.createComment('author A', 'authorA@test.com', 'test comment')
      .then((res) => {
        resolve()
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        resolve(err)
      })
  })
})
```

I would like to know if there's a way to be able to match partial of `POST` data?

Comment: This is actually related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637254/is-it-possible-to-apply-passthrough-within-a-mock-reply-using-axios-mock-adapt) that was meant to be a workaround to this hurdle, but has problem of its own...

Comment: What do you mean by _"match partial of `POST` data"_? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm able to to have my mock applied to "exact" match. In my example: `{ name: 'author A', email: 'authorA@test.com', body: 'test comment' }`. The question is, am I able to apply wildcards and say "apply mock on all POST requests that has `email == 'authorA@test.com'`?

Answer (score 5):

You can catch all `POST` requests to a specific `URL` and then manually match your conditions within the `reply` callback and `passThrough` if conditions don't meet, we can `passThrough` within the `reply` callback by passing the call to the `originalAdapter` like answered in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637254/is-it-possible-to-apply-passthrough-within-a-mock-reply-using-axios-mock-adapt/57580750#57580750).

```
mockHttpClient.onPost(/(\/comments)/i).reply((config) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(config.data);

  if (data.email == 'authorA@test.com') {
    return [200, 'response'];
  } else {
    // passThrough
    return mockHttpClient.originalAdapter(config);
  }
})
```

`NOTE` : you can have multiple `full match` data to the same `URL` if provided data is different, but for our own `partial match` implementation you can't add another request to the same `URL` and `method`, you will have to add the logic to match all wanted cases to one request.

Answer (score 1):

Since version v1.18.0 (22 Mar 2020) `asymmetricMatch` is supported.

```
mockHttpClient.onPost(/(\/comments)/i, {
  asymmetricMatch: (actual) => actual.email === 'authorA@test.com'
}).reply(527)
```